# Take picture, saving picture and loading in imageview, error

Tags: android, image, save, loading, photo

I want that when you press the button, it opens the camera mode. Then do you make a photo and confirmed this. Then the photo will be stored on the hard drive and and you go back to the normal layout and sees the image in the image view.

My problem is that after the photos confirm the app crashes.

```
    package de.example.camera;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;



public class Camera extends Activity {


ImageView iv;
public File mediaFile;
public Uri fileUri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.j_camera);
    iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.photo);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(1);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });

}

private File getTempFile(Context context){
    //it will return /sdcard/image.tmp
    final File path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName() );
    if(!path.exists()){
        path.mkdir();
    }
    return new File(path, "image.tmp");


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch(requestCode){
            case 0:
                final File file = getTempFile(this);
                try {
                    Bitmap captureBmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(file));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }

}
        Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);

    }
    private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type){
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));

    }private File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "YourFolderName");
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            Toast.makeText(null, "failed to create directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
    }
    if (type == 1){
        Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
        String ts = tsLong.toString();
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "photo"+ ts + ".jpg");

    }
    else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
    }
```

The error:

```
03-14 11:57:34.973  14565-14565/de.example.camera E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity {de.example.camera/de.example.camera.Camera}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3406)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3449)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at de.example.camera.Camera.onActivityResult(Camera.java:87)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5322)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3402)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3449)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: remove static from  `static File getOutputMediaFile(.....)` and  `static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(......)`

Comment: Thx @ Simple Plan. The camera save the picture but when I press the ok button of the camera crashes the app.

Comment: your static error is solved or not?

Answer (score 1):

Use this way to start the itent

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}
```

in onActivityResult

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

The image is stored automactly in the sd and you alse have it in the bmp

EDIT:

```
private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1
```

it was missing this,
you will get this value in the onActivity result, it will give you the info of witch request was made, in this case you will receive 1 in the requestCode

Comment: When I use your way to start the intent the "`REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE`" is marked red and it says "`Cannot resolve symbol 'REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE'`"

Comment: did you put the permission in manifest?

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" 
    android:required="true" />